# How to use tablesorter plugins cssStickyHeaders widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    var options = {
        sortList: [
            [1, 1]
        ],
        theme: 'ice',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'cssStickyHeaders'],
    };

    $("#myTable").tablesorter(options);

});
```

I use tablesorter and need to use cssStickyHeaders widget but I have two problems that I could not fix.

**1)** I have another sticky header on my page, and I need this tables sticky header to appear under it. I tried to understand widget options parameters from [**here**](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-css-sticky-header.html) but could not make it work.

**2)** CSS does not update automatically, so I have to turn on and off the developer tools in browser to make it work, to make the header move. In example everything works but it doesn't work with my page, though I do everything in the same way as it is presented in the example.

I am new to javascript. I hope someone will help me.

Comment: Maybe they just don't work together? This is why JQuery plugin's sometimes just don't work. Write your own if it's wrong?

Comment: @Liam , thank you for your reply. It is a native widget by tablesorter developers. So I find it strange. And I googled it, didn't find anyone to have the same issue.

Comment: You need to bear in mind jquery plugin's are made by developers for free. They generally come with no support or guarantees on their use. You pays your money you takes your chance. Personally I normally find all plugins (apart from the big ones) more hassle than they are worth. It sounds like your a bit out of your depth here.